# calling function from constructor inside class

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I created the following class:

```
class GlobalModal {
    constructor(text) {
        this.modal = document.getElementById('Modal');
        this.span = document.getElementById("closeModal");
        this.text = text;

        //Show the GlobalModal
        this.modal.style.display = "block";

        // When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
        this.span.onclick = function() {
            this.close();
        }

        // When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
        window.onclick = function(event) {
            if (event.target == this.modal) {
                this.close();
            }
        }
    }

    // Function to close the GlobalModal
    close() {
        this.modal.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

I'm trying to call the function `this.close();`

**Error**: this, close is not a function.

Is what I'm trying to do even possible? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Inside the event listener, `this` refers to the element that fired the event, not your class instance. I'm sure there is a dupe for this on SO

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use `this` in the callback you should use an arrow function which binds `this` to the lexical context:

```
window.onclick = (event) => {
   if (event.target == this.modal) {
      this.close();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
class GlobalModal {
    constructor(text) {
        this.modal = document.getElementById('Modal');
        this.span = document.getElementById("closeModal");
        this.text = text;

        //Show the GlobalModal
        this.modal.style.display = "block";

        // When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
        this.span.onclick = function() {
            this.close();
        }.bind(this)

        // When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
        window.onclick = function(event) {
            if (event.target == this.modal) {
                this.close();
            }
        }.bind(this)
    }

    // Function to close the GlobalModal
    close() {
        this.modal.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

As was pointed out by @ibrahim mahrir, you lose the context of `this` inside the event listener. `bind` explicitly sets the `this` value to whatever you give it as a parameter.